# Gentoo: cannot install sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.4.6, no error message

Tags: kernel, gentoo, emerge, portage

I am trying to install Gentoo on an old laptop following the online handbook. I got as far as installing the kernel sources (see [here](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:X86/Installation/Kernel)): the installation with

```
emerge --ask sys-kernel/gentoo-sources
```

seems to run fine, until it fails with no precise error message. The log file

```
/var/tmp/portage/sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.4.6/temp/build.log
```

contains no error message. The last lines in this file read

```
* Final size of build directory: 1 KiB
* Final size of installed tree: 623669 KiB

ecompressdir: bzip2 -9 /usr/share/doc
```

I also looked at `/var/log/emerge.log` which also does not contain any error message:

```
1473188561: Started emerge on: set 06, 2016 21:02:40
1473188561:  *** emerge --ask sys-kernel/gentoo-sources
1473188622:  >>> emerge (1 of 1) sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.4.6 to /
1473188622:  === (1 of 1) Cleaning (sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.4.6::/usr/portage/sys-kernel/gentoo-sources/gentoo-sources-4.4.6.ebuild)
1473188698:  === (1 of 1) Compiling/Merging (sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.4.6::/usr/portage/sys-kernel/gentoo-sources/gentoo-sources-4.4.6.ebuild)
1473189553:  === (1 of 1) Merging (sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.4.6::/usr/portage/sys-kernel/gentoo-sources/gentoo-sources-4.4.6.ebuild)
1473190741:  *** Finished. Cleaning up...
1473190743:  *** exiting unsuccessfully with status '1'.
1473190751:  *** terminating.
```

I do not know what I should check next. Any idea?

**EDIT**

Here is the content of `/var/tmp/portage/sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.4.6/temp/build.log` (I have removed some non-printable characters that appeared at the beginning of each line):

```
Package:    sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.4.6
Repository: gentoo
Maintainer: kernel@gentoo.org
USE:        abi_x86_32 elibc_glibc kernel_linux userland_GNU x86
FEATURES:   preserve-libs sandbox userpriv usersandbox
>>> Preparing to unpack ...
>>> Unpacking source...
>>> Unpacking linux-4.4.tar.xz to /var/tmp/portage/sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.4.6/work
>>> Unpacking genpatches-4.4-8.base.tar.xz to /var/tmp/portage/sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.4.6/work/patches
>>> Unpacking genpatches-4.4-8.extras.tar.xz to /var/tmp/portage/sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.4.6/work/patches
Excluding Patch #5000_enable-additional-cpu-optimizations-for-gcc.patch ...
Excluding Patch #5015_kdbus*.patch ...
Applying 1000_linux-4.4.1.patch (-p1) ...
Applying 1001_linux-4.4.2.patch (-p1) ...
Applying 1002_linux-4.4.3.patch (-p1) ...
Applying 1003_linux-4.4.4.patch (-p1) ...
Applying 1004_linux-4.4.5.patch (-p1) ...
Applying 1005_linux-4.4.6.patch (-p1) ...
Applying 1500_XATTR_USER_PREFIX.patch (-p1) ...
Applying 1510_fs-enable-link-security-restrictions-by-default.patch (-p1) ...
Applying 2700_ThinkPad-30-brightness-control-fix.patch (-p1) ...
Applying 2900_dev-root-proc-mount-fix.patch (-p1) ...
Applying 4200_fbcondecor-3.19.patch (-p1) ...
Applying 4567_distro-Gentoo-Kconfig.patch (-p1) ...
>>> Source unpacked in /var/tmp/portage/sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.4.6/work
>>> Preparing source in /var/tmp/portage/sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.4.6/work/linux-4.4.6-gentoo ...
>>> Source prepared.
>>> Configuring source in /var/tmp/portage/sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.4.6/work/linux-4.4.6-gentoo ...
>>> Source configured.
>>> Compiling source in /var/tmp/portage/sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.4.6/work/linux-4.4.6-gentoo ...
>>> Source compiled.
>>> Test phase [not enabled]: sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.4.6

>>> Install gentoo-sources-4.4.6 into /var/tmp/portage/sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.4.6/image/ category sys-kernel
>>> Copying sources ...
>>> Completed installing gentoo-sources-4.4.6 into /var/tmp/portage/sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.4.6/image/

Final size of build directory: 1 KiB
Final size of installed tree: 623669 KiB

ecompressdir: bzip2 -9 /usr/share/doc
```

Comment: What is in /usr/src?

Comment: @Giorgio: please post the whole output of `emerge gentoo-sources`

Comment: @Francesco Turco: Do you mean the content of `/var/tmp/portage/sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.4.6/temp/build.log`

Comment: @aventurin: `/usr/src` contains the directory `linux-4.4.6-gentoo` and a symbolic link to it named `linux`. However, I am not sure if the content of `linux-4.4.6-gentoo` is complete.

Comment: @Giorgio: in order to check if a package is fine you can use `equery check gentoo-sources`. Specify package version if needed. The `equery` command belongs to the `gentoolkit` package.

Comment: Please add the output of `ls -al /usr/src` to your question.

Answer (score 0):

simply have downloaded the kernel in / usr / src , you just need to fill it out by inserting the necessary forms for your pc
wiki gentoo: "Installing new kernel sources doesn't provide the user with a new kernel. It is necessary to make and install a new kernel from the new sources and then reboot the system to actually run the new kernel. "
[image]

Comment: I know that I need to compile to kernel after installing the sources. Since running `emerge --ask sys-kernel/gentoo-sources` reported a failure and each time I run it it tries to install the sources again and again, I was wondering if the sources are now correctly installed and whether I should try to compile using a broken package.

Comment: once downloaded the package you went into / usr / src and you did the various ` make menuconfig , make -jX make module_install etc ` ? it did not work?
if you really can not test genkernel

Comment: `cd /usr/src/linux` followed by `make menuconfig` gives: `make: *** No rule to make target 'menuconfig'.  Stop.`. As far as I understand, `emerge` has not completed the installation of the kernel source code.

Comment: sudo make menuconfig

Comment: emerges you downloaded the kernel , but may not know what configuration you want to use then you are creating the configuration , if you do not know do use genkernel

Comment: I was logged in as root, no need for `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

1. `rm -vR /usr/portage/distfiles`
2. `emerge-webrsync`
3. `emerge --sync && emerge -av sys-kernel/gentoo-sources`.

From the looks of your output, you didn't download the tarball correctly. If you'll notice @oscarandrea's screenshot his build directory is 4 kb's. Yours is only 1 kb.

Comment: @Giorgio See new comment in your question...